# Parametrizing "ternary cubic equals a square"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, polynomials

I am interested in an equation of the form

$$\displaystyle y^2 = f(x_1, x_2, x_3),$$

where $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, x_3]$ is a ternary cubic form. In particular, I am looking for an analogue of the 2-variable case, namely an equation of the form

$$\displaystyle y^2 = f(x_1, x_2), f \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2]$$

a binary cubic form. In the latter case, there are well-known syzygies that parametrize the equation. For instance, when $f$ is monic, we can rewrite $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1^3 - Ax_1 x_2^2 - Bx_2^3$ after a translation. Thus the above equation can be parametrized by a finite number of binary quartic forms, where $A,B$ are given by the $I,J$-invariants of the form.

Which objects parametrize the first equation, involving a ternary cubic? In other words, what is a "canonical" way of finding polynomials $R, Q_1, Q_2, Q_3$ which satisfy the syzygy induced by the first equation?